# How should I interpret output in the context of Anova and correlation cofficient generated as a part of Linear Regression Output?

Tags: correlation, anova, p-value, interpretation, linear

I am not clear why the p-value in the ANOVA and Correlations tables are not similar. Which one should I consider? It appears that it is a one-tailed in the correlation output and 2-tailed in the ANOVA, which indicates that there is no linear relationship between independent and dependent var. Please clarify.

In all my other regression outputs, I get the same p-value in the correlations and ANOVA tables. Why?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's because these correlations are given one tailed p values. The ANOVA is two tailed.  Note that 0.058 is double 0.029 and that there is a (one tailed) note.

Comment: I can note that. However, in another similar regression output, I see that the p-value in both the ANOVA and Correlations are p=0.001; I understand that it is significant in this case, p<0.05'. In the first case, should I say that since p=0.058, no relationships exist between the independent and the dependent var.

Comment: Please consult your software documentation, Vyas.  It will likely explain that what you quote as "p=0.001" means $p$ is some value between $0$ and $0.001$.

Comment: No. Regardless of the p value, you cannot say that no relationships exist. You can only say whether the relationship that does exist is statistically significant. Far too much emphasis is placed on p < 0.05, but, can you justify a one-tailed test?  If not, then, at the arbitrary level of 0.05 your results are not quite significant.